# Update node revision time in hook_entity_presave

Tags: 8, entities

In my site Drupal 8, I have custom entities (say components) and bundles. I load these entities in a node using the *Inline entity* module.
On the front-end, the contextual links provide two edit links: an edit link to edit the node with all inline entities and a link for a specific entity. When users use the second link, they get the edit page for that entity and its field values. Using the second link, the node last update value won't change.

I tried updating the node value in `hook_entity_presave()`, but it creates infinite redirection. How do I avoid it?

Comment: Make sure you don't call `$node->save()` in your presave, just update the time, the save will happen automatically.

Answer (score 2):

`hook_entity_presave()` cannot save any entity, or saving an entity will cause `hook_entity_presave()` to be invoked again. If your `hook_entity_presave()` implementation isn't able to understand it is invoked for the second time, and saves again an entity, it will cause an infinite loop.
Even if you implement [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave/8.8.x) and save a different entity, you will cause `hook_entity_presave()` to be invoked more than once, and that could cause issues.

In your case, if *components* is the entity type being edited, you should implement `hook_components_presave()`, get the node for which you need to alter the *Last changed* value, and save that node. As I said, I cannot guaranty there will not be issues, but at least your `hook_components_presave()` implementation won't be called twice, as it is invoked for the *components* entities, and it saves a node. The issues would come, for example, from a module that assumes that `hook_entity_presave()` is invoked only when a user edits or creates a node, and saves it.

Comment: this works perfectly. :)